# How to add icon inside a TabBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

How to add icon inside a TabBar in Flutter?
Thank you for any help

[image: Picture with an icon in a TabBar]

Answer (score 3):

If by icon you mean an Icon widget, they can be added directly to the `Tab` widget using its `icon` property.

```dart
Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.verified), text: 'Tab 1', ),
```

A complete example widget:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Tab>[
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.verified),
                  text: 'Tab 1',
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.new_releases),
                  text: 'Tab 2',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          body: TabBarView(children: <ExampleTab>[
            ExampleTab(),
            ExampleTab()
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

If you mean an image and no text, like the image you linked, you can use the `child` property to add any widget you like, which can be an `Image` widget, for example.

```dart
Tab(child: Image.network("https://placeimg.com/50/50")),
```

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: <Tab>[
                Tab(
                  child: Image.network("https://placeimg.com/50/50"),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.new_releases),
                  text: 'Tab 2',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          body: TabBarView(children: <ExampleTab>[
            ExampleTab(),
            ExampleTab()
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

You can add a border, rounded corners or other styles wrapping the `Image` in a `Container`.

Comment: I share [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68343026/17953229) regarding aligning icon and text in tabBar title.