# How to create a tabbar with icon and text in same row in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a tab bar which contains icon and text in the same row in tab.

I have tried below code to implement the same , due to which the icon and text are shown in column manner in tab.

```
     bottom: TabBar(
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(icon: new Image.asset("assets/images/ic_policy@2x.png",width: 18,height: 18), child: Text("Policies")
                            ),
                        Tab(
                          child: Container(
                            child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text("Policy Payments")),
                          ),
                        )
```

Can anyone guide me how to achieve the same.
My tabbar currently looks as below.

[image]

I want to design something like below :-

[image]

Comment: here is your solution  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51125324/11033305  ... Please let me know if it not works

Comment: I have already gone through the link, that is not what I want to craete. You can refer both the links of image I have shared in the question. @Why_So_Ezz

Answer (score 26, accepted):

why don't you define tabs like this?

```
Tab(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      Image.asset('assets/images/ic_policy@2x.png', width: 18, height: 18),
      const SizedBox(width: 8),
      Text('Policies'),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: The text property is required though.

Comment: it's not required